# azure function 404 not found when deployed from ARM, works fine when deployed from visual studio

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

I have an azure function that works when manually deployed via visual studio.
I then exported the ARM template from Azure portal and used this in a DevOps release pipeline.
The release pipeline succeeds after creating storage a hosting plan the function app and deploying the code to the function app.

When trying to access the function app however it throws a 404 not found error.
I've tried in postman and in the "code + test" section of the azure portal, but I get the same  404 error.

I assume the ARM template exported from azure portal is incorrect somehow but I cannot see how, as it deploys successfully.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

In case it is useful, below is the ARM template, almost as it was exported from the portal. I have changed function name and urls just to prevent any potential attacks.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "sites_myFuncName_name": {
            "defaultValue": "myFuncName",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "serverfarms_FuncsPlan_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/2sdr7sec-8sd7-78sd-a628-78asfd89sfed/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/hostingPlanName",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[parameters('sites_myFuncName_name')]",
            "location": "North Europe",
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "properties": {
                "enabled": true,
                "hostNameSslStates": [
                    {
                        "name": "myFuncName.azurewebsites.net",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Standard"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "myFuncName.scm.azurewebsites.net",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Repository"
                    }
                ],
                "serverFarmId": "[parameters('serverfarms_FuncsPlan_externalid')]",
                "reserved": false,
                "isXenon": false,
                "hyperV": false,
                "vnetRouteAllEnabled": false,
                "vnetImagePullEnabled": false,
                "vnetContentShareEnabled": false,
                "siteConfig": {
                    "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                    "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds": false,
                    "alwaysOn": false,
                    "http20Enabled": false,
                    "functionAppScaleLimit": 200,
                    "minimumElasticInstanceCount": 0
                },
                "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "clientCertEnabled": false,
                "clientCertMode": "Required",
                "hostNamesDisabled": false,
                "customDomainVerificationId": "XXXXX",
                "containerSize": 1536,
                "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
                "httpsOnly": true,
                "redundancyMode": "None",
                "storageAccountRequired": false,
                "keyVaultReferenceIdentity": "SystemAssigned"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'), '/ftp')]",
            "location": "North Europe",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "allow": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'), '/scm')]",
            "location": "North Europe",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "allow": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'), '/web')]",
            "location": "North Europe",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                "defaultDocuments": [
                    "Default.htm",
                    "Default.html",
                    "Default.asp",
                    "index.htm",
                    "index.html",
                    "iisstart.htm",
                    "default.aspx",
                    "index.php"
                ],
                "netFrameworkVersion": "v6.0",
                "requestTracingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2019",
                "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
                "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds": false,
                "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
                "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
                "publishingUsername": "$myFuncName",
                "scmType": "VSTSRM",
                "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
                "webSocketsEnabled": false,
                "alwaysOn": false,
                "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
                "virtualApplications": [
                    {
                        "virtualPath": "/",
                        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                        "preloadEnabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
                "experiments": {
                    "rampUpRules": []
                },
                "autoHealEnabled": false,
                "vnetRouteAllEnabled": false,
                "vnetPrivatePortsCount": 0,
                "localMySqlEnabled": false,
                "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 2147483647,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 2147483647,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
                "http20Enabled": false,
                "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "scmMinTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "ftpsState": "FtpsOnly",
                "preWarmedInstanceCount": 0,
                "functionAppScaleLimit": 200,
                "functionsRuntimeScaleMonitoringEnabled": false,
                "minimumElasticInstanceCount": 0,
                "azureStorageAccounts": {}
            }
        },

        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'), '/FuncName')]",
            "location": "North Europe",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "script_root_path_href": "https://myFuncName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/FuncName/",
                "script_href": "https://myFuncName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/bin/MyFuncName.dll",
                "config_href": "https://myFuncName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/FuncName/function.json",
                "test_data_href": "https://myFuncName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/Functions/sampledata/FuncName.dat",
                "href": "https://myFuncName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/FuncName",
                "config": {},
                "invoke_url_template": "https://myFuncName.azurewebsites.net/api/FuncName",
                "language": "DotNetAssembly",
                "isDisabled": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'), '/', parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "location": "North Europe",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_myFuncName_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "siteName": "myFuncName",
                "hostNameType": "Verified"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you add this code ``"appSettings": [
{
"name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"
"value": "1"
} to the `SiteConfig` Section in the above ARM Template and try!

Comment: hi. i tried this but experienced the same issue unfortunately.